# css boxes are not shown in the right place (when adding doctype)

Tags: html, css

ive written a css code that was kinda compatible to firefox and chrome.
    i didnt check internet explorer.
    when i opened my website with internet explorer the location of the boxes were all messed up.
    so i needed to add a doctype.
    but when i added the doctype my boxes arnt right shown at any browser.
    im not really experienced with css so any help is welcome. 
    how it should be (not internet explorer)
    " www.informatica-sj.bplaced.net "
    how it is when i add a doctype rule
    http://www.informatica-sj.bplaced.net/doctype/index.html
    both of my css and index.html
    http://pastebin.com/Rz1GH41a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your doctype should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This works across all browsers and should be added to the top of your HTML.

I noticed that you aren't declaring a value on the end margin property

```
margin: 50px 0 0 529;
```

Should be 529px;